# Is there any node packages(npm) for knife to bootstrap a node?

Tags: chef-infra, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, knife

What i tried to achieve?

I have an application deployed into Bluemix cloud-foundry environment which in turn needs to perform the following actions

1. ssh into a server that is existing on to a sandbox environment that exists in the same private network.
2. Trigger terraform to provision a vm in the sandbox environment
3. Trigger knife bootstrap command so that it will contact chef server and deploy the applications from the hosted chef server

What happens if i do so?

It throws out an error that ssh timed out.

Please help me to figure out what i am missing here

Comment: what other errors you see apart from the ssh time out ? what server are you trying to connect to ? what is your HTTP response code ? are you using the right authentication ?are certificates valid ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I am connecting to a Virtual machine with with redhat os. And http status is says 200 OK. yes. I am using ssh authentication as well as certificates are valide. My question here is, are there any modules for chef in node so that i can do a knife bootstrap.